# Viewing friends' uploads on Xbox One

Tags: xbox-network, xbox-one

Is there a way to view my friends' uploads in the 'Upload' app on the Xbox One? I thought this was a feature already, but when using the app tonight, all I saw were 'featured' uploaders, games, and featured uploads.

Why doesn't my account show this anymore?

edit: This video shows what I am talking about (around 1:21), and I don't seem to see my friends in this app anymore -

further research: I tried a few other things. For example, using my wife's account, she can see her friends videos. Also, I deleted my profile and then logged in again, and this did not help either. So it appears the app is fine and this is there - but my question now is - why doesn't this show for my account?

Comment: Can you verify that you can browse your friend's videos from their profile please? Go to view their profile and you should be able to see their videos when scrolling right (I can't remember what tab exactly). If not than it might have to do with your friend's privacy settings as you can set it to never share videos to anyone. Of course, if your wife's and your friend list overlap...

Comment: Yes, I could see all their videos in their actual profiles the whole time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While rather confusing and somewhat embarrassing of a fix - its mainly because I have not enough friends. Well, not enough friends with a One who are also actively uploading things.

I went through so much debugging with Xbox Twitter support, checking my profile, etc. Well, then to try something I followed Major Nelson, and it started working! But only for him. I then found a friend who had last updated a video, but that had been a few weeks ago.

This feature is very time dependent. So, instead of being my friends uploads, its more so their 'recent' uploads, and by recent does not mean their last, but recent in time, like a week or so.

Now that Titanfall is out a friend has been uploading some videos and it works as it should.

Comment: Good catch on the feed being time sensitive! Hadn't thought of that!